# Como pegar o início e fim da semana no Moment.js

Tags: javascript, data, momentjs

Eu uso o seguinte código para pegar o início e o fim da semana.

```
pegaData() {
    moment().locale();
    var agora;
    var datainicial;
    var datafinal;
    agora = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    console.log(agora);
    if(agora = 'Thusday'){
        datainicial = moment().subtract(4, 'days').calendar();
        datainicial = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');
        datafinal = moment().add(2, 'days').calendar();
        datafinal = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');
        
    }
    console.log(datainicial);
    console.log(datafinal);
}
```

E o código retorna certo a data inicial e final, só que não no formato que eu preciso, que seria `'DD-MM-YYYY'`.

Mas no momento da conversão, como eu chamo o `moment` novamente, ele converte a data atual. Como eu posso formatar a data sem chamar o `moment` novamente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se quer mudar o dia da semana, basta usar o [método `day`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/weekday/), passando um valor entre zero (domingo) e 6 (sábado):

```js
let agora = moment();

let inicio = moment().day(0); // domingo desta semana
let fim = moment().day(6); // sábado desta semana

// imprimir as datas no formato desejado
let formato = 'DD/MM/YYYY';
console.log('agora=', agora.format(formato));
console.log('início=', inicio.format(formato));
console.log('fim=', fim.format(formato));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Assim você não precisa ficar fazendo vários testes, como estava fazendo ("se hoje é quinta, soma 2 dias, etc").

Depois você atribui o resultado de cada um em uma variável e usa [`format`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) para mostrá-las no formato desejado.

No código acima, como hoje é 30/05/2019, então o valor inicial será 26/05/2019, e o valor final será 01/06/2019.

Comment: Muito obrigado man, onde vi sobre o moment.js não tinha o método day, muito obrigado por me mostrar ele, ajudou demais!!!!